# How to implement this - generate setter automatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets

In Standford CS 193P 2013-2014 Fall lecture 7, the instructor shows the following thing. But I can't reproduce that mysef in Xcode 6. Anybody knows that? (.gif can also be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ7ac.gif))

[image]

Comment: now a days the compiler has take the responsibilities for this

Comment: What “thing”, specifically, are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's code snippet.

You can create your own code snippet in XCode.

1. Type the template code in XCode
2. Copy it and drag it to the comment section in the Utility panel
3. Give a title and completion shortcut
4. Whenever you type the shortcut, XCode will show the auto-completion option

[image: XCode Snippeta]

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much. BTW, which kind of gif recorder do you use?